# probability mass function of a random pick from either of the other two random entities.

Tags: probability-distributions

This is not a hypothesis testing problem.

Let $Z$ be discrete non-negative random variable, such that it picks either the value of random variable $X$ with probability $p$ or the random variable $Y$ with probability $q$. The *pdfs* of both $X$ and $Y$ are known, is there a way to caculate the *pdf* of $Z$.

For instance: $$ X \: \sim Poisson(\lambda_0), \\
Y \: \sim Poisson(\lambda_1), \\  
Z = \begin{cases} X &\mbox{with probability  } p \\ 
Y &\mbox{with probability  } q . \end{cases} \\ f(Z)= ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is simply: $$f_Z(z) = \begin{cases}p \cdot f_X(z) + q \cdot f_Y(z)& \text{if } z \in \mathbb{N}_0,\\ 0 & \text{if }z \notin \mathbb{N}_0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is what I am expecting too.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, let's say $X$ and $Y$ be continuous RVs. We know that the probability that $Z$ is included within the interval $(t,t+dt)$ is $f_{Z}(z)dt$

So, 
$$
f_{Z}(z)dt = p\times f_{X}(z)dt +q\times f_{Y}(z)dt\\
\Rightarrow f_{Z}(z)= p\times f_{X}(z) +q\times f_{Y}(z)
$$
Note: Make sure of the domain of $X,Y \,and\, Z$

Similarly, for discrete cases, (simple multiplication of probability of events)
$$
P_{Z}(z) = p\times P_{X}(z) +q\times P_{Y}(z)\\
$$